# How to call CDialog::DoModal() with modified DLGTEMPLATEEX

Tags: c++, windows, mfc, modal-dialog

I know that I can create a dialog window using a [DLGTEMPLATEEX](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645398(v=vs.85).aspx) template in memory using [DialogBoxIndirectParam](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645461(v=vs.85).aspx).

But with MFC can I dynamically modify DLGTEMPLATEEX in [CDialog](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8zkyyhxw.aspx) before [DoModal](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/619z63f5.aspx) is called?

Comment: In theory you could overload `CDialog::DoModal`, that's where MFC loads the dialog template. I think I played around with this a while back and managed to change a few things in dialog template, but I gave up on it because it was too complicated. What is you want to do which can't be done with simple APIs?

Comment: From the documentation you linked: *"To construct a modal dialog box from a template in memory, first invoke the parameterless, protected constructor and then call InitModalIndirect."*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it to work. It turns out MFC has its own undocumented class for that: `CDialogTemplate`. I found [this page](https://neelaakash.wordpress.com/2007/12/31/change-default-dialog-font-of-cdialog/) with the following code to set font and its size. Then one can access `DLGTEMPLATEEX` by following logic in `CDialogTemplate` class methods -- step into `SetFont` method with debugger:

```
#include <afxpriv.h>        //Needed for CDialogTemplate

int CSimpleDialog::DoModal()
{
    CDialogTemplate dlt;
    int nResult;

    // load dialog template
    if (!dlt.Load(MAKEINTRESOURCE(CSimpleDialog::IDD))) {
        return -1;
    }

    // set your own font, for example “Arial”, 10 pts.
    dlt.SetFont("Arial", 10);

    // get pointer to the modified dialog template
    LPSTR pdata = (LPSTR)GlobalLock(dlt.m_hTemplate);

    // let MFC know that you are using your own template
    m_lpszTemplateName = NULL;
    InitModalIndirect(pdata);

    // display dialog box
    nResult = CDialog::DoModal();

    // unlock memory object
    GlobalUnlock(dlt.m_hTemplate);

    return nResult;
}
```